# Automatically update data labels on Excel chart (Excel 2016)

Tags: excel, charts, scatter-plot, excel-2016

I've created a scatter chart with the data below:

```
REF IMPACT  PROBABILITY
1.1 3       3
1.2 2       2
1.3 2       2
    #N/A    #N/A
    #N/A    #N/A
    #N/A    #N/A
```

Impact x axis, probability y axis, and ref as the data label. I formated data labels using "values from cell" command on the REF column (highlighting all the data, including the blank cells). All the data in this table are lookups from other tables if that matters.

The issue is: When I update the table with new values, the data points get added on automatically to the chart, but the labels show as blank as shown in the image.

[image: empty data labels]

Is there a way to have the labels update automatically? If the solution is VBA one, please give as much detail as possible as i'm not familiar with it